# how to post message on twitter wall without tweetbox using javascript / jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter, cordova

I have created application in Twitter.Now I want to post message on twitter wall.
My coding is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="ru">
<head>
    <title>Tweet Box</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8"/>
    <script src="http://platform.twitter.com/anywhere.js?id=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&v=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="twitterBox"></div>


    <script type="text/javascript">

      twttr.anywhere(function (T) {

        T("#twitterBox").tweetBox({
          height: 100,
          width: 400,
          defaultContent: "@devirtuoso"
        });

      });

    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

While I am clicing tweet button it display error:"something is technically wrong".and message does not post on twitter wall.

How to solve this error?
how to post message on twitter wall?
If it possible  without using tweet box  post message on the wall.

Please guide me.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

ensure the file which calling the twitter box is in the same domain....like if you have created your application with the domain name as....http://www.yourdomainname.com...then the file should be places in the http://www.yourdomainname.com/tweet.html...mention this as callback url as well....and test...it is a piece of cake...!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine (assuming your consumer key is right). Check your callback url.